# SQL query for Weekly Sales Report

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

- Retrieve three columns labeled day, qty_sold and total_profit in that order.
  day should be displayed in the 3-character format Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat and sorted ascending in that order.
- Only retrieve sales from the past week.
- If there are no sales on a particular day of the week (as might be the case on a holiday), the row should still be included in the report with qty_sold and total_profit columns as 0.
- Net profit per item is calculated as `qty_sold * (price - cost)`. Total profit for a day is the sum of the net profit of every item sold on that day.
  Do not format any numbers as currency.

Here's what i got so far any help would be greatly appreciated

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.order_time,"%a") AS day
FROM sales_order s 
INNER JOIN order_item o on o.sales_order_id=s.id 
INNER JOIN menu_item m on m.id =o.menu_item_id
GROUP BY day;
```

This is supposed to be the output

[image: output]

Comment: First hint: if you need a record for every day, even when there are no sales, then you need to generate a dataset that holds just these 7 date records. The normal way of doing this is to use a CTE to hold the SQL to generate the data and the left join the sales_order table to it. If the order time is a timestamp rather than a date then you will need to allow for this when joining the date column from the CTE to it

Comment: I'm not really advance in writing complex SQL queries, normally i would use an ORM such as sequlize can you please elaborate more or provide some exemples ?

Comment: If you search Stackoverflow for something like "Generate a range of dates using SQL" you will find lots of examples on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT day,COUNT(menu_item_id) AS qty_sold,SUM(price - cost) AS total_profit
FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS id,"Sun" AS day
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,"Mon"
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,"Tue"
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,"Wed"
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,"Thu"
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,"Fri"
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,"Sat") AS dow
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_order AS s ON dow.id = DAYOFWEEK(s.order_time)
INNER JOIN order_item AS o ON o.sales_order_id=s.id 
INNER JOIN menu_item AS m ON m.id=o.menu_item_id
WHERE s.order_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 + WEEKDAY(current_date) DAY) AND s.order_time < CONCAT(current_date," 00:00:00")
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY dow.id
```